# Do all numbers have equal probability to be chosen from a randrange?

Tags: python

When a random.randrange function is called, is the chance for numbers to be picked out from it exactly equal? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the distribution is uniform, meaning that from n inputs every input has 1/n chance to be selected.

I don't know the actual algorithm implemented but you can see the source code here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py

As far as I know there is a lot of math involved in generating pseudo random numbers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Edit: as a fun exercise I made a script who generates 1 million random numbers between 0 and 5 and I keept count of each of them, and as you can guess the number of counts for each number should be around the same at around 200000:

```
from random import randrange
from pprint import pprint

c = {}
for i in range(1000000):
    r = randrange(0, 5)
    if r not in c:
        c[r] = 0
    c[r] += 1

pprint(c)
```